# Create an array of objects from array of objects which has nested fields JavaScript/es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested, array.prototype.map

I am working on an array of objects which has nested attributes, Is there any way to write a recursive function to achieve below output mentioned

```
const firstArray = [
  {
    groupId: '1',
    childRows: [
      {
        groupId: '1a',
        childRows: ['abc', 'def'],
      },
      {
        groupId: '1b',
        childRows: ['pqr', 'xyz'],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupId: '2',
    childRows: [
      {
        groupId: '2a',
        childRows: ['abz', 'dxy'],
      },
      {
        groupId: '2b',
        childRows: ['egh', 'mno'],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How to write a function in es6 such that below output is returned

```
[
  { groupId: '1', childRows: ['abc', 'def', 'pqr', 'xyz'] },
  { groupId: '1a', childRows: ['abc', 'def'] },
  { groupId: '1b', childRows: ['pqr', 'xyz'] },
  { groupId: '2', childRows: ['abz', 'dxy', 'egh', 'mno'] },
  { groupId: '2a', childRows: ['abz', 'dxy'] },
  { groupId: '2b', childRows: ['egh', 'mno'] },
];
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Actually I wanted to find an object then get its childRows  like this const getList = (id) => {
      const newList = firstArray
        .find(w => id == w.groupId)
       .childRows.map((x) => ({ name: x }));
       
      return newList;
    };
    console.log(getList(2)); // [{name:"pqr"},{name:"xyz"}]   ,   but here in my above question there is nested fields

Comment: If it is 1 level nesting should work with a forEach inside a reduce

Comment: Does the output have to be in the same order as your example?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this recursive function. The output objects are in the intended order.

```js
const getNestedGroups = (array, groups = []) => {
  const finalArray = [];

  // Group list should be empty as it is filled here.
  groups.length = 0;

  array.forEach((group) => {
    if (group.childRows.length > 0) {
      // If the group does not have nested groups we just append it to the group list.
      if (typeof group.childRows[0] === "string") {
        groups.push(group);
      }
      // If the group has children, the same function is called for them.
      else {
        // Call function for child
        const directChildren = [];
        const childGroups = getNestedGroups(group.childRows, directChildren);

        // Makes an object from the direct children (which were also made from their direct children if they had some).
        let groupWithChildren = { groupId: group.groupId, childRows: [] };
        childGroups.forEach((child) => {
          groupWithChildren.childRows.push(...child.childRows);
        });

        // Adds child to group list.
        groups.push(groupWithChildren);
        groups.push(...directChildren);
      }
    }
  });

  // Adds the new groups to the output array.
  finalArray.push(...groups)
  return finalArray;
}
```

You then call the function.

```js
console.log(getNestedGroups(firstArray));
```

Here is the output.

```
[
  { groupId: '1', childRows: [ 'abc', 'def', 'pqr', 'xyz' ] },
  { groupId: '1a', childRows: [ 'abc', 'def' ] },
  { groupId: '1b', childRows: [ 'pqr', 'xyz' ] },
  { groupId: '2', childRows: [ 'abz', 'dxy', 'egh', 'mno' ] },
  { groupId: '2a', childRows: [ 'abz', 'dxy' ] },
  { groupId: '2b', childRows: [ 'egh', 'mno' ] }
]
```

Edit : Thanks to J. Villasmil, I saw we can optimize `array1 = array1.concat(array2)` with `array1.push(...array2)`. I so updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I tried to explain you with comments in the code

```js
const firstArray = [
    {
      groupId: '1',
      childRows: [
        {groupId: '1a',childRows: ['abc', 'def']},
        {groupId: '1b',childRows: ['pqr', 'xyz']}
      ]
    },
    {
      groupId: '2',
      childRows: [
        {groupId: '2a',childRows: ['abz', 'dxy']},
        { groupId: '2b',childRows: ['egh', 'mno']}
      ]
    },
];

function solution (arr){
  const result = [] 

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  
      let parent = [] // this is where I will accumulate all the "childRows" of the same parent
      
      let oldResultLengt = result.length // remember this for now
      
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].childRows.length; j++) {
      
          const _childRows = arr[i].childRows[j].childRows // save the specific child array 
          
          result.push({'groupId':arr[i].childRows[j].groupId, 'childRows': _childRows}) // put the object into result array
          
          parent.push(..._childRows) // add to parent array

      }
      /* in this part of the code, at the first iteration the let result looks this:
      [
        {"groupId": "1a", "childRows": ["abc", "def"]},
        {"groupId": "1b", "childRows": ["pqr", "xyz"]}
      ]
      
    but oldResultLength is still 0, so I use splice to insert the parent element before their own childrens
 */
     result.splice(oldResultLengt, 0, {'groupId' : arr[i].groupId, 'childRows': parent})
  }
  return result
}

console.log(solution(firstArray))
```

Function without comments:

```js
function solution (arr){
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
      let parent = []
      let oldResultLengt = result.length
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].childRows.length; j++) {
          const _childRows = arr[i].childRows[j].childRows
          result.push({'groupId':arr[i].childRows[j].groupId, 'childRows': _childRows})
          parent.push(..._childRows)
      }
     result.splice(oldResultLengt, 0, {'groupId' : arr[i].groupId, 'childRows': parent})
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to say this is that the `childRows` prop contains either strings or objects, and the `childRowsIn` function returns the childRows's strings and the `childRowsIn` the childRows's objects

```js
function childRowsIn(object) {
  const childRows = (object.childRows || []).filter(e => ['string','object'].includes(typeof e));
  return childRows.map(e =>
    typeof e === 'string'? e: childRowsIn(e)
  ).flat()
}

const object = getData();
console.log(childRowsIn(object))

function getData() {
  const firstArray = [{
      groupId: '1',
      childRows: [{
          groupId: '1a',
          childRows: ['abc', 'def'],
        },
        {
          groupId: '1b',
          childRows: ['pqr', 'xyz'],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      groupId: '2',
      childRows: [{
          groupId: '2a',
          childRows: ['abz', 'dxy'],
        },
        {
          groupId: '2b',
          childRows: ['egh', 'mno'],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  return {
    childRows: firstArray
  };
}
```

Comment: Can .flat pe avoided, as duplicates can exist

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur - flat doesn't remove duplicates, rather it moves the contents of nested arrays into the same array as their parents... it "flattens" the nested arrays

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap`, `concat` and `destructuring` can simplify as

```js
const process = (arr) =>
  arr.flatMap(({ groupId, childRows }) =>
    childRows.concat({
      groupId,
      childRows: childRows.flatMap(({ childRows }) => childRows),
    })
  );

const firstArray = [
  {
    groupId: "1",
    childRows: [
      {
        groupId: "1a",
        childRows: ["abc", "def"],
      },
      {
        groupId: "1b",
        childRows: ["pqr", "xyz"],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupId: "2",
    childRows: [
      {
        groupId: "2a",
        childRows: ["abz", "dxy"],
      },
      {
        groupId: "2b",
        childRows: ["egh", "mno"],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(process(firstArray));
```